# Getting an empty record back when using ember data and sails.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, sails.js

Preface: I am new to ember.

I have a node server set up in [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!) and I am using ember for the front end. In my route file I have the following:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        if(window.sessionStorage.getItem('current_user_id')){
            App.CurrentUser = window.sessionStorage.getItem('current_user_id');
            this.store.find('user', App.CurrentUser);
            this.store.find('list', App.CurrentUser);
        }   
    }
});
```

Which should be pre-loading the lists that belong to the current user so that when the user goes to `#/lists/index` all of their lists are already loaded.

This is the response from the server when I call `#/lists/:id`

```
{
  "lists": [
    {
      "name": "popcicle",
      "user_id": 1,
      "createdAt": "2013-12-31T05:26:39.970Z",
      "updatedAt": "2013-12-31T05:26:39.970Z",
      "id": 48
    },
    {
      "name": "happy dance",
      "user_id": 1,
      "createdAt": "2013-12-31T05:28:51.220Z",
      "updatedAt": "2013-12-31T05:28:51.220Z",
      "id": 49
    },
    {
      "name": "something",
      "user_id": 1,
      "createdAt": "2013-12-31T05:34:53.616Z",
      "updatedAt": "2013-12-31T05:34:53.616Z",
      "id": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

However when I open the ember inspector in chrome and go to data -> App.List it shows 4 items:

```
Id  Name
1   
48  popcicle
49  happy dance
50  something
```

Which breaks my view because name is `undefined`

**TL/DR** I either need to know why ember data has this blank list and how to get rid of it, or how to do a conditional iteration inside my view so that an undefined name doesn't break my application.

Here is my view code incase that's helpful:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="lists">
    <div class="left-nav">
      {{partial "listNav"}}
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_listNav">
   <h4> Lists </h4>
    <div class="column-span2 left-nav">
        <ul> 
            {{#each list}}
            <li>
                 {{name}}
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul> 
        {{#link-to "lists.new"}}Create List{{/link-to}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things that I noticed:

- Your model hook doesn't have a return statement (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).
- You're trying to return two things, it seems, `user` and `list`. (Maybe you need RSVP.hash: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3006#issuecomment-21110139)
- Calling store.find(type, id) will look up a single resource, not a collection.
- The `/lists/:id` response should show a single list. `/lists` should show all lists.
- You are using the `ApplicationRouter` instead of the `Lists(Index)Router`, which is probably what you want.

Comment: So I'm using the application router because this is preloading data if there is already a session for the user. So user logs in leaves then comes back latter, if their session is still alive I want to reload all their lists even if they are not on the lists page. Also, the `/lists/:id` is really pointing at `/user/:id/lists` because lists belongs to user.